# What is the strongest reply to Czyzewski Opening?

Tags: opening, analysis

I was exploring *hypermodern* openings and had found **Czyzewski Opening**.

```
[fen ""]

1.e4 e5 2.b3
```

How I should react to this type of situation on the board. Is this some kind of trap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2.b3 is so vanishingly rare after 1.e4 e5 that you really should not bother preparing anything against it unless you have a friend who plays it all the time or something. Emms in *Play the Open Games as Black*, a repertoire book for Black after 1.e4 e5, does not even mention it.

> How I should react to this type of situation on the board.

*Bologan's Black Weapons in the Open Games* suggests starting with 2...Nf6 3.Nc3 Bb4, which seems as good as anything.

> Is this some kind of trap?

No.